# How to obtain new data from SSR in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So I am using a headless CMI with Next.js, and when I update a post in a `[slug]` page, the new data is not shown in it until a really long and unknown time. Here is the code I am using. I want it to get the latest data after updating from the CMI if I refresh the page. However, it does not show the latest data, but the old data still, even after refreshing.

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ params }: { params: Post }) {
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: PostDetailsDocument,
    variables: { slug: params.slug },
  });

  return {
    props: {
      post: data.post,
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: does console.log(data) show the old data in your console even after udpating?

Comment: Yep. Unlike in dev, where the new data is reflected. @tusharshahni

Comment: What is the `client` thing? Is it from this CMI npm package or something? It might have some in build cache, for example, that is disabled automatically in dev. Or it sends some cache header in production mode and this CMI might have setting to turn caching off.

Comment: It is an Apollo client with cache set to new cache()

Comment: So the issue only happens in production mode? Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: The problem has been solved. See: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/main/examples/with-apollo